# Handlebars y LowDB. Como paso los datos de mi JSON a mi plantilla?

Tags: json, express, parsear, handlebars

estoy teniendo muchos problemas tratando de cargar mis datos desde lowDB ha Handlebars via Express.

Mi archivo JSON incluye:

```
{
  "games": [
    {
      "id": "Yltw6o9XpK",
      "title": "game 1 is pog!",
      "url": "www.000.google.com"
    }
  ],
  "simulcasts": []
}
```

El cual compone toda la base de datos. Intente cargar los datos de "Games" utilizando un #each

```
{{#for game in games}}
 {{{game.title}}}
{{/endfor}}
```

En mi codigo de express, le digo a handlebars que es games via:

```
const game = new FileSync("./database.json");
const db = low(game);
games = db.get("games");

....

helpers: {
                games: JSON.stringify(games),
```

No parece funcionar, como cargo mi json ha handlebars?

Answer (score -1):

es importante declarar correctamente el template que vas a usa, asi

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  </div>
</script>
```

Enseguida, tienes que hacer referencia al contenedor en donde vas a mostrar lo que deseas, y hacer la instancia de handlebar

```
var source = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

Y por ultimo asignarle un objeto al render que estas ejecutando, en tu caso mandas el objeto que contiene a games

```
var context = { title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!" };
var html = template(context);
```

Comment: Evitemos la autopromocion en las publicaciones por favor.